# Powerflash FDT - Why aren't i getting predictive text for MXML?

Tags: apache-flex, fdt

Recently downloaded Powerflash (FDT) to compare with Flash Builder, but it doesn't seem to cleverly colour the MXML code, nor provide me with predictive text. Is that only for action script files?

Thanks guys

Comment: Have you tried looking for help here: http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/developer-tools/fdt/support/  This isn't really a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please be more specific - what do you mean by 'colour the MXML code' This could mean different things. It could be:

1. Error highlighting
2. Semantic Highlighting
3. Occurrence marking

FDT has all three. Please see attached screenshot for an example. [image: MXML Semantic Highlighting]

For predictive text, do you mean autocompletion. FDT has autocomplete for components and properties of MXML files. Please see attached screenshot for an example. [image: MXML autocomplete]

Comment: Thanks strange i can see your screenshots but for me i don't get that... it doesn't allow me to get the autocompletion. It may be the project configuration or something but i am using eclipse flash builder in conjunction and it seems to work with that... do i need to change the nature of anything differently?

Comment: Please add a screen shot of where your cursor is and what the proposal list looks like.

Comment: Some places might not have autocomplete. Admititdly, FDT is not the best IDE for Flex only work. If you only do Flex dev, Flash Builder is best. IF you do mostly AS - go with FDT>

Comment: Thanks yeah my AS stuff works fine but yeah the Flex stuff doesn't. I have a lot of gripe with Flash Builder, plus its only 32 bit which is annoying... THanks anyway, i actually removed the demo so i can't take any screenshots but hope this helps others! thanks mate